# New-MgBookingBusinessService, how to set "Customer information"?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

How to select informations customer at to display and required that we need when I creeate un service with New-MgBookingBusinessService ?

- Customer email
- Phone number
- Customer address
- Customer notes

Thanks,

```
$Params = @{
    BookingBusinessId = "test3@domissori.fr"
    DefaultDuration = "00:15:00"
    DisplayName = "FirstBooking3"
    DefaultPriceType = "free"
}

New-MgBookingBusinessService @Params
```

[image]